# "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start" without any stack trace

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I keep getting this error while I try to start Tomcat in Eclipse. No other message or details just a pop up with this message: "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start." Tomcat works fine in the terminal so I don't see what could be the issue. I looked at countless solutions, nothing worked.
What I tried:
 - Changing the ports
 - Reinstalling server
 - Deleting .snap file
 - Deleting temp folder 
 - Removing runtime environment
 - Restarting everything
So basically all the suggestions that were made in different posts, nothing works, anybody have any idea what else can I try?
Ps. It can't be the web.xml since I get the same message when I try to start the tomcat server on it's own without any project.
Can it be some permission issues somewhere in windows?

Comment: Was there anything in the Console view?

Comment: Absolutely nothing

Comment: Try a downloaded Tomcat tar file directly from Apache that you expand somewhere under your home directory rather than an installed version.